# How to execute script during image build in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following at the end of my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT bash -C '/usr/local/bin/setup_php_settings';'bash'
```

If I am not wrong that `/usr/local/bin/setup_php_settings` will be executed each time the container is started. If so then I have a few installation stuff (like [this](http://files.zend.com/help/Z-Ray/content/installing_z-ray_on_linux.htm) ZRay for example) inside that script that I would like to move to another script that would be executed just once on image build process let's say.

The content of the `setup_php_settings` (whithout the ZRay part) is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
set -e

PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=${PHP_ERROR_REPORTING:-"E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE"}
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

mkdir -p /data/tmp/php/uploads
mkdir -p /data/tmp/php/sessions
mkdir -p /data/tmp/php/xdebug
chown -R www-data:www-data /data/tmp/php*

ln -sf /etc/php5/mods-available/zz-php.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/zz-php.ini
ln -sf /etc/php5/mods-available/zz-php-directories.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/zz-php-directories.ini
ln -sf /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/ /usr/share/php/Zend
a2enmod rewrite
php5enmod mcrypt

# Apache gets grumpy about PID pre-existing files
: "${APACHE_PID_FILE:=${APACHE_RUN_DIR:=/var/run/apache2}/apache2.pid}"
rm -f "$APACHE_PID_FILE"

source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

The question is, how do I execute such new script during image build? Using `CMD`? Any other workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct directive for this is `RUN`. This would run the script on image build. in your case -

```
RUN /usr/local/bin/setup_php_settings
CMD bash
```

Comment: Not so fast, I have added the content of the `setup_php_settings` file and maybe you want to re-check your answer :) I would say based on your answer that will be better to have a separated `RUN` command for the installation stuff, what do you think?

Comment: All of the steps in your script, except for maybe the last line should be run during image build (i.e a separate `RUN` command). The last one looks more like something I would put inside a `CMD` command in my dockerfile, Although I would substitute the `source` part with `ENV` commands in the dockerfile (assuming this file only sets env vars)

Comment: Ok, can you add an example of your possible setup? Sorry I am still learning Docker :)

Comment: This is kinda of a different question than "how to run a script on image creation". The short answer would be - run 2 containers, one for apache (you can use their official image - https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) and one for your php app, and link them together using the --link flag. it's a bit advanced but if you want to dive into docker I recommend starting building your apps ready for container work right from the start.